# Element-ui - disable animation on el-tag

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I've been digging into the code, but can't figure out where the on-enter animation is coming from:

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/471037/

Code of the fiddle:

.html

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="showUndone"> <label>Show undone ?</label>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" v-if="todo.done || !todo.done && showUndone">
      <el-tag>{{todo.text}}</el-tag>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

.js

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      showUndone: false,
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<el-tag>` transitions are on by default.  Use the attribute `disable-transitions` to disable:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="showUndone"> <label>Show undone ?</label>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" v-if="todo.done || !todo.done && showUndone">
      <el-tag disable-transitions>{{todo.text}}</el-tag>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/7xaefujh/1/